# Why I can not select certain .Net framework in a new project even if they're installed?

Tags: c#, frameworks, visual-studio-2019

Good day all,
I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2019 and when I start a new c# project (doesn't matter if it is console, WPF or Windows forms) I can only choose from the .Net frameworks: core 3.0, core 3.1 and 5.0 while on the machine are installed also other frameworks like 3.5, 4.5, 4.6, 4.8 etc.. .[VS_Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE2uN.jpg) The strange fact is that if I look to older c# projects I can choose from all the frameworks installed on my pc. How can I use one of those framework on a new project

Also as You can see in the attached image in the solution explorer the "Reference" tab does not appear, how can I make it appear?

Comment: have you installed just the fameworks, or also the SDKs?

Comment: There are two distinct flavors of ".NET" now, the ".NET Framework" and ".NET Core" (and, to confuse things, ".NET 5" & ".NET 6" are part of the Core family). When you start a project, you choose a project _Template_ (like "Console" or "WPF"). There are separate templates for the Framework and for the Core. Make sure you get the right one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Flydog57's comment; take a look at this "New Project" window:

[image: x]

See after the project name on eg the Console app it has "(.NET Core)" and after the WPF one it has "(.NET Framework)"? That defines what you'll see in your targeting box.. Make sure you pick the one you want to later choose some relevant version from